# How can I create JSON structured data for search results in PHP?

Tags: php, json, json-ld

So, I have a music search engine here: http://zenek.neocsatblog.mblx.hu

When you want to search something, the search URL looks like this:

http://zenek.neocsatblog.mblx.hu/search/love%20is%20gone%20david%20guetta

I want to provide structured data for every element on this page, with JSON and `script` tags. Unfortunately, this does not really work.

I mean, I only get the first element of this page, but I doesn't get any loop. So, the HTML in this case looks like this:

```html
<script>

{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ImageObject",
  "author": "David Guetta - Love Is Gone...",
  "contentLocation": "Budapest, Hungary",
  "contentUrl": "http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000112948246-z6q0y7-large.jpg",
  "description": "David Guetta - Love Is Gone...",
  "name": "David Guetta - Love Is Gone..."
      }
</script>
```

And my PHP code looks like this:

```php
<?php
$avatar = $GLOBALS['sys']->img($search->artwork_url, "100", $search->user->avatar_url); 
$title =$GLOBALS["sys"]->sh_title(urldecode($search->title), "25"); 
?>
<script>
<?php echo '
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ImageObject",
  "author": "'.$title.'",
  "contentLocation": "Budapest, Hungary",
  "contentUrl": "'.$avatar.'",
  "description": "'.$title.'",
  "name": "'.$title.'"
      }
'
?>
</script>
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just use JSON, without the `<script>` tags? To return multiple results, return a JSON array.

Comment: I fear a littlebit from new things.
I see this example in the schema.org, and I whant to do this exactly as there showed.

Comment: Build an indexed array with sub-arrays and use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). There is zero reason to rely on homebrewed and error-prone JSON.

Comment: In this way?
http://pastebin.com/fYBY1n5B

Comment: Anyway I tryed out and the result is:
`@context: ["http:\/\/schema.org"]
@type: ["ImageObject"]
author: ["'.David Guetta - Love Is Gone....'"]
contentLocation: ["Budapest, Hungary"]
contentUrl: ["'.http:\/\/i1.sndcdn.com\/artworks-000112948246-z6q0y7-large.jpg.'"]
description: ["'.David Guetta - Love Is Gone....'"]
name: ["'.David Guetta - Love Is Gone....'"]`
This not realy heee becouse I still not get datas for other results.

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to just print json array of objects you can do this:**

```
<?php
$array = [
    [
        "@context" =>  "http://schema.org",
        "@type"  => "ImageObject",
        "author"  => "title",
        "contentLocation" => "Budapest, Hungary",
        "contentUrl" => "http://content.url",
        "description" => "description text",
        "name" => "title"
    ],
    [
        "@context" =>  "http://schema.org",
        "@type"  => "ImageObject",
        "author"  => "title",
        "contentLocation" => "Budapest, Hungary",
        "contentUrl" => "http://content.url",
        "description" => "description text",
        "name" => "title"
    ]
];

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array); // use json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) for debugging

?>
```

Result with JSON_PRETTY_PRINT will be

```
[
    {
        "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org",
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "author": "title",
        "contentLocation": "Budapest, Hungary",
        "contentUrl": "http:\/\/content.url",
        "description": "description text",
        "name": "title"
    },
    {
        "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org",
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "author": "title",
        "contentLocation": "Budapest, Hungary",
        "contentUrl": "http:\/\/content.url",
        "description": "description text",
        "name": "title"
    }
]
```

**If you want to print json array straight to your script you can do this:**

```
<?php
$array = [
    [
        "@context" =>  "http://schema.org",
        "@type"  => "ImageObject",
        "author"  => "title",
        "contentLocation" => "Budapest, Hungary",
        "contentUrl" => "http://content.url",
        "description" => "description text",
        "name" => "title"
    ],
    [
        "@context" =>  "http://schema.org",
        "@type"  => "ImageObject",
        "author"  => "title",
        "contentLocation" => "Budapest, Hungary",
        "contentUrl" => "http://content.url",
        "description" => "description text",
        "name" => "title"
    ]
];
?>
<button type="button" id="button">CLICK ME</button>
<script>
    var array = <?php echo json_encode($array) ?>;

    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert(JSON.stringify(array));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You shoud use a header, before you print your json.

```
<?php
$avatar = $GLOBALS['sys']->img($search->artwork_url, "100", $search->user->avatar_url); 
$title =$GLOBALS["sys"]->sh_title(urldecode($search->title), "25"); 
$result = array(
    "@context" => "http =>//schema.org",
    "@type" => "ImageObject",
    "author" => "'.$title.'",
    "contentLocation" => "Budapest, Hungary",
    "contentUrl" => "'.$avatar.'",
    "description" => "'.$title.'",
    "name" => "'.$title.'");

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
// Alternatively
echo '<script>var result = ' . json_encode($result) . ';</script>';
```